# Sum and aggreggation of columns in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, aggregation

Hellow! I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["1", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2"],
                   "status" : ["active", "active", np.nan, "notactive", "other", "other"]})
```

And I need to calculate new DataFrame witch columns:

1. New1 = Number of agreement with status "active" for each ID
2. New2 = Number of agreement with missing status (np.nan) per each ID
3. New3 = Number of agreement with status "notactive" or "other" per each ID
   Results which I need should be like below, but crosstab does not work because New3 column contain "nonactiv" and "other" status:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some code? Show us if you tried and which things you are stuck with... It's not just like "do my homework".

Comment: I tried pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['status']) but it does not work because it do not combine in New3 "nonactive" and "other", it only each status counts separately

Comment: then shouldn't restate your question to ask how to map anything other than `np.nan` and `'active'` to another value?

Comment: Asish M so you think to replace NaN, nonactive and other to 2 statuset i calculate it ? but could you suggest some code ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because contains question in graphics rather than the searchable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 - You can use `factorize()` to count `NaN` values as their own group without having to remap AND help with naming the columns (all you have to do is use `add_prefix()`:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(index=df['ID'], 
                  columns=df['status'].replace('other', 'notactive').fillna('active2')
                  .factorize()[0]+1)
        .add_prefix('New').reset_index())
df

Out[1]: 
col_0 ID  New1  New2  New3
0      1     1     1     0
1      2     1     0     2
2      3     0     0     1
```

Solution 2:
`NaN` values will be excluded from the tabulation with `pd.crosstab` so you can use `fillna()`. You also have to make `other` values equal to `notactive` per your condition. Now, you can use `crosstab` and get your desired results. From there, just rename the columns:

```
df = pd.crosstab(index=df['ID'], 
                 columns=df['status'].replace('other', 'notactive').fillna('active2'))
       .reset_index()
df.columns = ['ID', 'New1',  'New2', 'New3']
Out[2]: 
  ID  New1  New2  New3
0  1     1     1     0
1  2     1     0     2
2  3     0     0     1
```